# C++: How might one draw an ASCII character at a specific location in command prompt

Tags: c++

Basically, I want to be able to create a function where I can go:

```
draw('C', x, y);
draw('h', x+1, y);
draw('a', x+2, y);
draw('r', x+3, y);
```

and command prompt will display `Char` at the given x and y position

All I could figure out in my research is that I will have to `include <windows.h>`, which I have very minimal experience with, and use the pre-defined content in that library.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)

Comment: Use the [`SetConsoleCursorPosition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025(v=vs.85).aspx) function followed by the `WriteConsole` function.

Comment: `GetConsoleOutputCP()` or `SetConsoleOutputCP()`, first. There's no reason to use ASCII on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help you get started.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx for more info.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    HANDLE screenBuffer = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER,
        NULL);

    if (screenBuffer == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("CreateConsoleScreenBuffer failed - (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    if (!SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(screenBuffer))
    {
        printf("SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer failed - (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(screenBuffer);
        return;
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
    {
        DWORD numCharsWritten;
        WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(screenBuffer, "X", 1, COORD{(short)x, 1}, &numCharsWritten);

        Sleep(1000);
    }

    CloseHandle(screenBuffer);
}
```

Comment: I get one error though with this piece of code: WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(screenBuffer, "X", 1, COORD{(short)x, 1}, &numCharsWritten);  It says "Error: argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR" (underlining the "X")

Comment: The code as I pasted it works if you compile from the command line.  I'm guessing you've put it into a project which has the (better) default of UNICODE strings.  Replace the "X" with L"X" and you should be fine.

Comment: Works now.  Thanks you.